# How to set proxy only if ethernet cable is plugged in

Tags: proxy, ethernet

I know there's the possibility to set proxy from the command line using `export http_proxy="http://USER:PASSWORD@PROXY_SERVER:PORT"`

I'd like to automatically set it up only when Ethernet cable is plugged in (I'm aware of the existance of `ifplugd` but I am not sure how to configure it).

Where should I start?

edit: I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 and I manually configured the proxy from Settings->Network->"Network proxy"